# Xamarin.ios: Image Asset Catalogs not loaded in the app

Tags: ios, iphone, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm facing a very strange problem. I have multiple images xcassets in my xamarin.ios project. One of them is used for appicons and launch screen. The problem is that while building the app. Non of them appear (appicon or images used inside the app). Sometimes they appear after building the app for the 2nd or 3rd time. But on a new clean fresh installation never happens. I have checked around and seems it's a common problem with VS users for sometime. Any ideas or recommendations ?

I know there's a workaround to use PNG images instead of asset catalogs. But I'm using a pre-compiled 3rd party framework that needs images to be included as xcassets otherwise I see issues in images layout.

xCode 10.1
Simulator is on iOS 12.1

Some of the things I tried:
-I have tried 2 different versions of Visual studio, including the latest one (8.0.9) 
-I have tried on simulator and device and same behavior.
-I have tried cleaning,rebuilding all, restarting simulator, uninstalling the app..
-I have tried removing and readding the xcassets to the project
-I have tried moving the xcasset to the root directory of the project
-I have tried to edit (.csproj) file and replace slashes with backslashes
-I have tried removing appicon and launch from info.plist
And nothing really worked, still the problem persists.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after spending hours investigating the problem, I figured out what the problem is exactly.

I'm sharing it so anyone doesn't need to spend time trying here and there :

My Solution had many projects inside. The main project has references to the other projects. One of these other projects have an empty (Assets.xcasset,Resources folder) which made Visual Studio get confused sometimes and often shows or hides the resources folder in the main project.
Obviously it should be a top priority to include the Resources folder and the appicon from the main project or at least raise an error or warning of files/folders duplication. But unfortunately there isn't. So be careful with that.

Good luck folks!

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT
Yes I will, I think it needs 48 hours of waiting before marking it as the right answer..